# Sonnification javascript only returning a single note

Tags: javascript, node.js, midi

I have been trying to use a node.js script to turn some data into music. The script is only returning a single note for some reason:

The orignal script on github: https://github.com/wbkd/from-data-to-sound had  res.concat(scribble.scale('c', but the threw an error Invalid Scale name.

```js
const scribble = require('scribbletune');

// example data
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];

const min = Math.min(...data);
const octaves = [...Array(5)].map((d, i) => i + 1); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

// creates array of notes like 'c1', 'd1', 'e1', 'gb1', 'ab1', 'bb1', 'c2', ...
const notes = octaves.reduce((res, octave) =>
  res.concat(scribble.scale('c1 major', 'whole tone', octave, false))
, []);

const midiData = scribble.clip({
  notes: data.map(value => notes[value - min]),
  pattern: 'x',
  noteLength: '1/16',
});

// write the MIDI file 
scribble.midi(midiData, 'data-sonification.mid');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From scribbletune doc:

> each x implies a note on event

[scribbletune docs/core/clip](https://scribbletune.com/documentation/core/clip)

Since you're passing only 1 'x' as a pattern in `scribble.clip`, it only plays 1 note. In order for all the notes to be played, you can try something like this:

```
  const midiData = scribble.clip({
    notes: data.map(value => notes[value - min]),
-   pattern: 'x', // only play 1 note
+   pattern: 'x'.repeat(data.length), // repeat this pattern for each note in data
    noteLength: '1/16',
  });
```

Comment: You absolute hero. Thanks a million